# Second monitor not detected on system with nVidia card

Tags: 12.10, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I switched from 12.04 to 12.10 yesterday evening (fresh install). Now I'm struggling with my second monitor, which I can't configure.

In 12.04, after installing the system, I got a notice telling me that I'd need to install further graphic drivers. After doing so I had a nvidia control center where I was able to configure everything.

However, 12.10 didn't ask me about graphic drivers and there's also no nvidia-settings application installed. I can't see the second external monitor (connected via DVI), only the internal one and one of the external monitor (connected via VGA, both monitors are the same model).

I have a HP Elitebook 8530w with an nVidia graphics card (Quadro, I don't know where to show the exact type of the card). When booting, Ubuntu configures dual screen for one of the external monitor and the internal laptop monitor. But I somehow can't tell him to turn off the internal monitor and use the second external monitor instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have been able to resolve my problem by using this post: http://linuxers.org/howto/how-remove-nouveau-drivers-ubuntu

I had to use `/etc/init.d/lightdm stop` instead of the `/etc/init.d/gdm stop` in the documentation (only right after booting without having logged in via graphical login).

Also, prior to starting the nVidia driver setup, I had to run `apt-get install linux-headers-3.5.0-17-generic`, because the nVidia driver setup searched for those.